# Bash: tr command with variables representing chars

Tags: bash, variables, ascii, tr

I want to use the tr command to map chars to new chars, for example:

> `echo "hello" | tr '[a-z]' '[b-za-b]'` Will output: `ifmmp`

(where each letter in the lower-case alphabet is shifted over one to the right)

See below the mapping to new chars for `'[b-za-b]'`:

> `[a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z]` will map to:
>
> `[b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a]`

---

However, when I want it to rotate multiple times, how can I use a variable to control the rotate-value for the tr command?

Eg: for a shift of 1:

> `echo "hello" | tr '[a-z]' '[b-za-b]'` without variables and:
>
> `echo "hello" | tr '[a-z]' '[(a+$var)-za-(a+$var)]'` where $var=1
>
> here I have: `(a+$var)-z` representing the same as `b-z` and
>
> ....................`a-(a+$var)` representing the same as `a-b`

I have tried converting the ascii value to a char to use within the tr command but I don't think that is allowed.

My problem is that bash is not interpreting:

`(a+$var)` as the char `b` when $var=1

`(a+$var)` as the char `c` when $var=2

... etc.

**How can I tell bash to interpret these equations as chars for the tr command**

**EDIT**

I tried doing it with an array but it's not working:

> chars=( {a..z} )
>
> var=2
>
> echo "hello" | tr '[a-z]' '[(${chars[var]}-z)(a-${chars[var]})]'

I used: `(${chars[var]}-z)` to represent `b-z` where var=1

Because `${chars[1]}` is `b` but this is not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Use a language with `ord()` and `chr()` functions, Python, Perl, C, etc....

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do cannot be done using `tr` which does *not* handle your requirement. Moreover when you meant to modify and use variables to add to glob patterns in `bash` which is something you cannot possibly do.

There is a neat little trick you can do with bash arrays!. The `tr` command can take expanded array sequence over the plain glob patterns also. First define a source array as

```
source=()
```

Now add its contents as a list of character ranges from `a-z` using brace expansion as

```
source=({a..z})
```

and now for the transliterating array, from the source array, construct it as follows by using the indices to print the array elements

```
trans=()
```

Using a trick to get the array elements from the last with syntax `${array[@]: (-num)}` will get you the total length - num of the elements. So building the array first as

```
var=2
trans+=( "${source[@]:(-(26-$var))}" )
```

and now to build the second part of the array, use another trick `${array[@]:0:num}` to get the first `num` number of elemtents.

```
trans+=( "${source[@]:0:$(( $var + 1 ))}" )
```

So what we have done now is for a given value of `var=2`, we built the `trans` array as

```
echo "${trans[@]}"
c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z a b c
```

Now you can just use it easily in the `tr` command

```
echo "hello" | tr "${source[*]}" "${trans[*]}"
jgnnq
```

You can just put it all in function and print its value as

```
transChar() {
    local source
    local trans
    local result
    source=({a..z})
    trans=()
    var="$2"
    input="$1"
    trans+=( "${source[@]:(-(26-$var))}" )
    trans+=( "${source[@]:0:$(( $var + 1 ))}" )
    result=$( echo "$input" | tr "${source[*]}" "${trans[*]}" )
    echo "$result"
}
```

Some of the tests

```
transChar "hello" 1
ifmmp

transChar "hello" 2
jgnnq

transChar "hello" 3
khoor
```

Answer (score 2):

rot-random:

```
# generate alphabet as arr:
arr=( {1..26} ) 
i=$(($RANDOM%24+1))
# left and right
l=$(echo ${arr[$i]})
r=$(echo ${arr[$i+1]})
# reusing arr for testing:
echo ${arr[@]} | tr "a-z" "$r-za-$l"

echo "secret:"  | tr "a-z" "$r-za-$l" ; echo $l $r $i
amkzmb:
h i 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use octal `\XXX` character codes for characters to do what you intend. Using the octal codes you could do any arithmetic manipulations to numbers and then convert them to character codes

```bash
# rotr x
#
# if 0 <= x <= 25 rotr x outputs a set specification
# that could be used as an argument to tr command
# otherwise it outputs 'a-z'

function rotr(){
   i = $(( 97 + $1 ))
   if [ $i -lt 97 ] ; then
        translation='a-z'
   elif [ $i -eq 97 ] ; then
        translation='\141-\172'  # 141 is the octal code for "a"
                                 # 172 is the octal code for "z" 
   elif [ $i -eq 98 ] ; then
        translation='\142-\172\141'
   elif [ $i -lt 122 ] ; then       # $i is between 99 and 121 ("c" and "y") 
        ii=$(echo "obase=8 ; $i" | bc)
        jj=$(echo "obase=8 ; $(( $i - 1 ))" | bc)
        translation=\\$ii'-\172\141-'\\$jj
   elif [ $i -eq 122 ] ; then
        translation='\172\141-\171'
   else                              # $i > 122
        tranlation='a-z'
   fi
   echo $translation
}
```

Now you could use this as follows

```
echo hello | tr 'a-z' $(rotr 7)
```

prints

```
olssv
```